# Fatorial de um número escolhido pelo usuário

Tags: c#, fatorial

Não estou conseguindo fazer estar expressão de fatorial, que é:

> 1 + (1/1!) + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + ... + (1/n!)

Sendo que o número `n` é digitado pelo usuário.

Meu código:

```
Console.WriteLine("A expreção 1 + (1/1!) + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + ... + (1/n!)");
double fatorial = 1, s;
Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de fatoação");
s = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (double n = 1; n <= s; n++)
{
    fatorial = fatorial * n;

    Console.WriteLine("############################################################################");
    Console.WriteLine("A fatoração de " + n + " é: " + fatorial);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("############################################################################");
    Console.WriteLine("1 ÷ pela fatoração de " + 1 / fatorial);
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
double conta = (1 / fatorial + fatorial);
Console.WriteLine("1 ÷ pela fatoração de " + conta);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar uma função separada para calcular o fatorial, como já sugerido nas outras respostas. Mas também dá para fazer tudo em um único *loop*.

A conta começa com 1, e depois soma 1/1!, 1/2!, 1/3!, etc. Mas como 3! = 3 x 2! e o valor de 2! já foi calculado no termo anterior, não tem porque calcular tudo de novo. Basta multiplicar 3 pelo valor anterior (2!). E na próxima iteração, quando tiver que calcular 4!, não precisa fazer um *loop* para calcular tudo (1 * 2 * 3 * 4), basta fazer 4 x 3! (sendo que 3! já foi calculado na iteração anterior). E assim por diante...

Então fica assim:

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite n: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double total = 1;
double denominador = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    denominador *= i;
    total += 1.0 / denominador;
}
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Na primeira iteração, `denominador` é 1, e é multiplicado por 1 (então seu valor equivale a 1!), assim temos 1/1!, que é somado ao total.

Na segunda iteração, `denominador` é multiplicado por 2 (ou seja, seu valor é o mesmo que 2!), e 1/2! é somado ao total.

Na terceira iteração, `denominador` é multiplicado por 3. Como seu valor anterior era 2!, então ele passa a ser 3 x 2! que é o mesmo que 3! - então 1/3! é somado ao total.

E assim por diante...

---

Não que seja errado fazer uma função ou *loop* separado somente para calcular o fatorial. Mas você estará fazendo *loops* a mais que não são necessários nesse caso.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de dois ciclos, um para calcular o factorial, e outro para ir acumulando
o valor.

```
Console.WriteLine("A expreção 1 + (1/1!) + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + ... + (1/n!)");
Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de fatoação");
int s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double acum = 1;
for (int n = 1; n <= s; n++)
{
    int fatorial = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) fatorial *= i;

    acum += (1 / (double)fatorial);

    Console.WriteLine("A fatoração de " + n + " é: " + fatorial);
    Console.WriteLine("1 ÷ pela fatoração de " + acum);
    Console.WriteLine("######################################");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
Console.WriteLine("1 ÷ pela fatoração de " + acum);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Veja funcionando em [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RfqkvI)

Versão LINQ:

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de fatoação");
int s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double result = 1 + Enumerable.Range(1, s).Select(n => 1 / (double)Enumerable.Range(1, n).Aggregate((a, b) => a * b)).Sum();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Em uma pesquisa rápida na internet, existem 3 formas de calcular um fatorial, que são:

#### Usando Loop

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace factorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, number, fact;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            fact = number;
            for (i = number - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nFactorial of Given Number is: "+fact);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

#### Usando Recursividade

```
public double factorial_Recursion(int number)
{
    if (number == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return number * factorial_recursion(number - 1);
}
```

#### Usando While

```
public double factorial_WhileLoop(int number)
{
    double result = 1;
    while (number != 1)
    {
        result = result * number;
        number = number - 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Exemplos retirados de https://www.csharpstar.com/csharp-program-to-calculate-factorial/

No seu caso você não estava fazendo o fatorial para cada número.

#### Exemplo do seu problema usando recursividade

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A expreção 1 + (1/1!) + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + ... + (1/n!)");
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de fatoração");

        var qtde = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double fatorial = 0;
        double resultado = 1;

        for (var item = 1; item <= qtde; item++)
        {
            fatorial = factorial_Recursion(item);
            resultado += (1 / fatorial);

            Console.WriteLine("############################################################################");
            Console.WriteLine("A fatoração de " + item + " é: " + fatorial);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("############################################################################");
            Console.WriteLine("1 ÷ pela fatoração de " + 1 / fatorial);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("1 ÷ pela fatoração de " + resultado);
    }

    private static double factorial_Recursion(int number)
    {
        if (number == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return number * factorial_Recursion(number - 1);
    }

}
```

Url https://dotnetfiddle.net/8nZ9ep